# How to add readonly fields in outlook contact via plug-in

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I have a requirement of adding certain read only fields(once created then it will not change) in existing contacts or while creating new contacts in Outlook through my vsto plug-in. I am able to add user defined fields using `ItemProperty` and `UserProperty`:

```
Outlook.ContactItem newContact = this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem) as Outlook.ContactItem;

Outlook.ItemProperty itemProp = newContact.ItemProperties.Add("PermanentID", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olNumber, false, 1);
itemProp.Value = "123123";
newContact.Email1Address = "abc@d.com";

Outlook.UserProperty mailUserProperty = newContact.UserProperties.Add("ID1", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olNumber, false, 1);
mailUserProperty.Value = "123345456";

newContact.Save();
```

This does create fields in the Contact but they are not read only. Is there any way around to create read only fields or adding new properties to the contact item that can be shown within the Contact window?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry to say, but there is no way to prevent the user from editing the values of `UserProperty` objects.

They are exposed in Outlook and freely editable by the user or any other add-in.

The only possibility I see it creating a custom pane in VSTO, where you show the value of the field 'read-only', but that doesn't prevent the user from actually changing it.

Comment: can we add any other custom properties to achieve the same?

Comment: I couldn't find any way to do it and also it not told anywhere that it can't be done.

Comment: `UserProperties` are *user* properties, not 'some hidden in the background' properties.

Comment: @SumitPannu: Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user property instead. See the UserProperties property of the ContactItem class. To display them in the inspector window you can develop a form region. You are free to display the required information in the read-only way.

See [How to: Add a Form Region to an Outlook Add-in Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386177.aspx) to get started.

Comment: He is adding user properties, right? See the code. It is about making them read-only.

Comment: I see the ItemProperties in the beginning of the code. Anyway, the problem is not in making user properties read-only. The property values shouldn't be modified by the end users.

Comment: OP uses `newContact.UserProperties`. Editing isn't something you can prevent. Outlook as editors for it by default.

Comment: Outlook doesn't provide any standard way for editing user properties. Only other add-ins or applications can re-write the data. So, the form region can be used to display the information with the read-only mode enabled.

Comment: still i can edit the value of user property. I want to store some key value pair in contact object so that once saved it can not be edited again.

Comment: i need this type of functionality because i want some other application to access my contacts and its properties for some other tasks.

Comment: I am sure that typical users don't know how to display user property. Anyway, instead you may consider adding [storage items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864182(v=office.15).aspx) to the contacts folder. I.e. store corresponding to contacts hidden items with your properties.